# get content item in Orchard layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I define a content type and taxonomy now I want to get some content item on layout in Orchard.
I don't want to develop module I only want a simple query.

I want query and get content items (with fields no lazy loading approach) with specific taxonomy on a alternative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at projections, this is what they are for, David Hayden has a nice introduction to them on his blog: http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/projector-module-in-orchard-cms